# What's with the Donut/Froyo?

Tags: android-versions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the names of the various versions of the Android OS, and how are these names chosen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11400/what-are-the-names-of-the-various-versions-of-the-android-os-and-how-are-these-n)

What the heck is Froyo?

Are android trying to be cool with the naming conventions?

.. oh wait, they.. they're alphabetical, right? Just like Linux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They haven't publicized how they came up with why the version naming scheme they did.  [There has been speculation about what future names would be](http://phandroid.com/2009/05/12/android-cupcake-donut-and-beyond/) and [more speculation](http://www.techknots.com/mobiles/all-android-code-names-leaked/).  All of this could have [something to do with obesity](http://www.blog.moby1.co.uk/2010/01/industry-news/android-naming-convention-contributing-to-obesity.html), but we may just never know.

After Froyo it looks like it's Gingerbread and then Honeycomb.  The original name for Froyo was apparently going to be Flan.  I think speculation about what the next names will be helps generate buzz and adds a playful element to the product.

Comment: I assume it has to do with the opposite of apple. Not healthy, fattening, and spreading like wildfire.

Comment: @Dmitriy Likhten: Yes, and intelligently designed, and a decent price/performance ratio, and secure, and OpenSource, and free, and Linux, and using Java (Python would have been better), and no politics in appstore, and no manufacturer lockin, unlike Apple. Sugar on steroids, so to say. One needed be really stupid to bite in a sour Apple when there's sugar on steroids nearby. Besides, the rumors of sugar being so unhealty are vastly exaggerated. Today it's sugar, tomorrow the 0815-flu, and the day after tomorrow potatoes.

Answer (score 3):

The updates have been:

- 1.5 Cupcake
- 1.6 Donut
- 2.0/2.1 Eclair
- 2.2 Froyo (Frozen Yogurt)
- 2.3 Gingerbread
- 3.0 Honeycomb
- 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich
- 4.1 Jelly Bean

Each codename has been a sweet treat.

Comment: That list looks like the ingredients for some kind of sickening recipe :)