# What are the names of the various versions of the Android OS, and how are these names chosen?

Tags: android-versions

Many people refer to Android versions by "codenames" rather than version numbers (e.g. Android "Gingerbread"). What are the names of the various versions of the Android OS, and how are these names chosen?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Each version of Android since 1.5 has been developed with a specific codename. These codenames are chosen alphabetically and have thus far been dessert items (or, generically, sweet/sugary foods). Some codenames are associated with more than one version number, while others are limited to only a specific one, and the reason for this inconsistency is not currently known. The naming typically appears to correspond to changes in the developer API levels, but this is not always true (example: 3.0 and 3.1 are both "Honeycomb" but have different API levels).

The following names are used for the currently existing Android releases. Note that versions 1.0 and 1.1 were not publicly named. However, Android 1.1 was internally referred to as "Petit-Four" (noted in [Traroth's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/11404/981), confirmed [here](http://source.android.com/source/overview.html)). Also, starting from Android 10, Google stops announcing the codename publicly and instead referred to the version number, though they may still have the codename for internal purposes (reff: [XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-codename-android-14/)):

**Cupcake:**

- Android 1.5

**Donut:**

- Android 1.6

**Eclair:**

- Android 2.0
- Android 2.1

**Froyo:** ([short for "frozen yogurt"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/what-is-a-froyo))

- Android 2.2

**Gingerbread:**

- Android 2.3

**Honeycomb:**

- Android 3.0
- Android 3.1
- Android 3.2

**Ice Cream Sandwich:**

- Android 4.0

**Jelly Bean:**

- Android 4.1
- Android 4.2
- Android 4.3

**KitKat:**

- Android 4.4

**Lollipop:**

- Android 5.0
- Android 5.1

**Marshmallow:**

- Android 6.0

**Nougat:** (official name: https://twitter.com/Android/status/748642375908589568)

- Android 7.0
- Android 7.1

**Oreo:**

- Android 8.0
- Android 8.1

**Pie:**

- Android 9.0

**Android 10 (Quince Tart)**

**Android 11 (Red Velvet Cake)**

**Android 12 (Snow Cone)**

**Android 13 (Tiramisu)**

**Android 14 (Upside Down Cake)**

Answer (score 20):

Eldarerathis summarized it very well. To add some things: The 1.1 version was internally called *Petit Four* by Google, and that's how it all began. Google is installing a giant pastry on their lawn at Mountain View each time a new version is about to be launched.

You can see pictures of that display at different stages here:

[image: Overall display (Cupcake to Eclair, with Nexus One)] Donut, Android logo, Nexus one, Cupcake, Eclair

[image: Honeycomb]Froyo

[image: Eclair, Froyo, Gingerbread, Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich] Gingerbread, Icecream Sandwich, Honeycomb

[image: Kit-Kat] KitKat, Jellybean

[image: Lollipop] Lollipop

[image: Marshmallow] 
**Marshmallow**

[image: Nougat]
**Nougat**

[image: Oreo]
**Oreo**

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels contains a table that links all the naming mess, excerpt:

```
Platform Version    API Level    VERSION_CODE
Android 6.0         23           M
Android 5.1         22           LOLLIPOP_MR1
Android 5.0         21           LOLLIPOP
...
```

[Web archive link](https://web.archive.org/save/https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels).

Comment: Just a heads-up that this list doesn't seem to reflect codenames anymore since M. P has released already, yet M/N/O's dessert names aren't in.