# How can I use a Bluetooth keyboard with my Android 4.0 phone?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, bluetooth, keyboard

My phone recently received an upgrade to Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) over the air and want to connect a Bluetooth keyboard to it.

My phone is a Samsung Nexus S 4G (Sprint) and the keyboard is a Logitech Bluetooth Keyboard for Android 3.0+. I had tried to connect the keyboard earlier, while running Android 2.3.x, with little success. What information I could find at the time suggested that Android lacked a Bluetooth keyboard "driver" prior to Honeycomb, so I was enthusiastic about the upgrade to ICS.

Sadly, however, doing what's obvious isn't working for me:

1. Enable Bluetooth in my phone settings.
2. Turn on the keyboard.
3. *(Keyboard appears in list of Bluetooth devices on phone.)*
4. Select keyboard from list of devices.
5. *(Prompt with PIN appears on phone.)*
6. Enter PIN on keyboard.
7. *(Keyboard shows on the phone as paired.)*

At this point, however, no further settings present themselves. The configuration for the keyboard only allows renaming and unpairing. The keyboard doesn't appear in the Keyboards and Input settings at all. Nor, of course, does simply typing on the keyboard cause input to appear on my phone.

Can this combination of hardware be made to work? How can I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any custom keyboards installed? I've found that when I pair the external Bluetooth keyboard (tried two models) the phone errors and reports you must change back to the standard Samsung IME keyboard before the it will type. You can manually change the input method with the hot key inside any writing app, but the message will reappear and convert the keyboard back to Samsung IME.

Comment: I've pared this down quite a bit because your original post was, in all honestly, incredibly difficult to follow due to all of the extraneous commentary and formatting issues. Also, please don't ask questions within answers, they're not an appropriate place to post them (although in answer to your now removed question, see http://android.stackexchange.com/a/11401/981).