# Why confectionary names are used in naming the android versions?

Tags: android-versions

Except alpha and beta, all the versions of android have been named based on confectionary items. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Slightly related: [What are the names of the various versions of the Android OS, and how are these names chosen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11400/)

Answer (score 1):

The following is an excerpt from [a CNN article](http://www.cnn.com/2011/TECH/innovation/02/04/google.honeycomb.android.names/):

> "It's kind of like an internal team thing, and we prefer to be a little bit -- how should I say -- a bit inscrutable in the matter, I'll say," said Randall Sarafa, a Google spokesman. "The obvious thing is that, yeah, the Android platform releases, they go by dessert names and by alphabetical order for the most part."
>   "For the most part" because two versions of Android, 2.0 and 2.1, were both called Eclair. And because Google won't say what it called the first two versions of Android, which you can assume started with "A" and "B."
>
> "As far as the public knows, it started with Cupcake," Sarafa said.
>   "I have some ideas, but I don't actually know for sure," he said of the first two Android names. "That was, jeez, like four years ago."

Comment: In what way does it answer the question?

Comment: `It's kind of like an internal team thing, and we prefer to be a little bit -- how should I say -- a bit inscrutable in the matter, I'll say.` --**There is no *functional* reason why it is named that way**. It's kinda like a motto, in a way, just for fun.